# .Net cannot get private method by reflection

Tags: .net, reflection, private-methods

I have a problem getting a private method using reflection. 
Even with BindingFlags.NonPublic and BindingFlags.Instance it doesnt work.
The HandleClientDrivenStatePropertyChanged is defined on the same class as the CreateRadioPropertyInstances method.

```
 class Program
 {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         RadioPropertiesState state = new RadioPropertiesState();
      }
 }

 internal class RadioPropertiesState : BaseRadioPropertiesState
 {
 }

 internal class BaseRadioPropertiesState
 {
     public BaseRadioPropertiesState()
     {
          CreateRadioPropertyInstances();
     }

     private void CreateRadioPropertyInstances()
     {
          // get the method that is subscribed to the changed event
          MethodInfo changedEventHandlerInfo = GetType().GetMethod(
               "HandleClientDrivenStatePropertyChanged",
               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | 
               BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
     }

     private void HandleClientDrivenStatePropertyChanged
         (object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     }
}
```

GetMethod returns null. 
What can be the problem?

[edited code]

Comment: Strange, works fine for on .NET 4. Try to play with BindingFlags

Comment: Another guess is that it could be caused by lack of some permissions. How do you invoke use `class X`? Is it loaded into different domain or from remote source, of smt similar?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. It should be fine - of course, if this method somehow ends up being invoked on a derived class, it won't find it...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: i posted more code demonstrating it

Comment: @leozilla: That doesn't look like a complete program to me. Where's the Main method?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: now i posted a runnable program

Comment: @leozilla: Well, it wasn't complete (no using directive), it wasn't properly formatted (the closing brace isn't shown as part of the code) and it didn't demonstrate the problem (you called the `GetMethod` method, but didn't show anything about the result). It's *really* useful to have a sample which we can just copy, paste, compile, run and see *immediately*, without any changes, that the problem is reproducible. Fortunately your code was enough to solve the issue in this case - see my answer - but please bear this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is exactly as I suggested in my comment - you're trying to find the method based on the *execution time type* of the object, which is `RadioPropertiesState`... but it's not declared in that type or visible to it.

Change your `GetMethod` call to:

```
MethodInfo changedEventHandlerInfo = typeof(BaseRadioPropertiesState)
                                         .GetMethod(...)
```

and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get private members you need to call `GetMethod` on the exact type where it was declared, and not a derived type.

`BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` does not work here, since the method is private.